# global jquery method for disable submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way from where I can disable my submit button on every form submit.When user submit the form on anywhere in the application.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this you can use jQuery's `:submit` selector. You could use an attribute selector, as in other answers, however this is flawed because a button without a `type` attribute will be a submit button by default.

```js
$(':submit').prop('disabled', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <button>Empty button</button> <!-- this is a submit button too! -->
  <button type="submit">Submit button</button>
  <button type="button">Basic button</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the selector like this `$('input[type=submit]')` .And apply the disable property true with [`prop()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwivtrbHo8zVAhVKRo8KHVrWBFUQFgiHATAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fprop%2F&usg=AFQjCNHaMBB-3221pUloi4_sHJpwg7mWnA) function

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type=submit],button[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" class="qu-more" value="Add">
<button type="submit">Add</button>
```

Comment: Don't forget that a `<button>` without a `type` attribute is a `submit` by default, so your selector wouldn't match that.

Comment: But I want to run this method globally for all the submit methods performing in the whole application. How can i do that ?

Comment: you could add this js in you `main.js` file And add the line inside the `document.ready` function.just like see the updated answer

Comment: But how this one works when I want to submit any form. If i do this on document.ready  then this will just disabled the submit button globally and not even let me submit the forms. I dont think you are getting my point. I want to disable the buttons while submission process of the form so that user didnt click it twice for multiple enteries and I want to do this globally so that my whole application forms work like this.

Comment: disable the  button after submit wright.your question was clear like your comment.Update the question with these comments

Answer (score 1):

**Use attr selector:**

```
$('[type="submit"], form button').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

**Edit**
Thk Rory about button.

Comment: Don't forget that a `<button>` without a `type` attribute is a `submit` by default, so your selector wouldn't match that.

Comment: Unfortunately your `form button` selector isn't quite right either as that will select `<button type="button">` elements, which are not submits